# Django Rest Framework Ordering Serializer.data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a 3 table and they releated between each other. Also i have some `serializers.SerializerMethodField` which is "elapsed_time" this field calculating elapsed_time so how can i order my Entites according to that MethodField. One way that i found i'm sorting serializer.data this returns OrderedList but this way taking so much time for 2k record.

```
serializer = self.get_serializer(entites, many=True)
result_page = get_pool_ordered_queryset(serializer.data)
```

get_pool_ordered_queryset function takes OrderedDict and sorting.

```
serializer_data = sorted(serializer_data, key=lambda k: k['elapsed_time'], reverse=True)
```

Like this but when i add 2k record its taking almost 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your question is how to speed up the process.

First of all you don't pass `OrderedDict` to `get_pool_ordered_queryset`, you pass `list` of `dict` values, that's what `serializer.data` returns.

Then you spent most of your time, computing 2k times your `elapsed_time`. You should try to move this part of computation to SQL and sort by it there.

You should probably be using `annotate` of django queryset, and the `order` by it.

This would drastically decrease your computation time.

Comment: I mean i dont need to get elapsed_time. I just need to sort by serializers.methodfield and one way to sort this field i must convert to serializer queryset to serializer.data then i can get that field and python uses timsort for OrderedDict so this is taking so much time